# Trigger dual functions, one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have two different functions, I want the first one to run when I shake my iPhone the first time and the second one to run the second time I shake my phone, after that I want it to start over.

I'm using the gShake plugin for jQuery so the shaking part is already finished. But how do I trigger the two functions every other time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the times shaked in a variable something like:

```
var shaked_times = 0;
```

and when the shake event is triggered (you said that this is already done) you start counting

```
shaked_times++;
```

and with a simple if statement you run your 2 functions like so:

```
if (shaked_times == 1) {
   function1();
}
else if (shaked_times == 2) {
   function2();
   shaked_times = 0;
}
```

and you reset the variable when it reaches 2

Hope this ideea helped
Let me know!

CHeers!

Comment: Thank you very much! But after a couple of failures I realized that it needs to be changed to this:  var shaked_times = 1;
        shaked_times++;
            
                if (shaked_times == 1) {
                    some functions here...
                    shaked_times = 2;
                }   else if (shaked_times == 2) {
                    some functions here...
                    shaked_times = 1;
                }